# Dynamic category module for price range based category

Tags: module, category, price, cron, dynamic

Thanks in advance.

I am looking for a script or module that will run via cron and remove products from a category if their price is above 5 USD also it will add products that have a cost up to 5 USD.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 Dynamic Sale Category extension allows you to display all the products set up for sale using special prices automatically under offers or sale category of your site without manual intervention. It supports pagination and layered navigation with filters just like another normal category.

- Display all the products set up for sale using special prices automatically
- Provide an option to hide the Sales category from the navigation
- Automatically assigns products to sales/offers category from catalog price rules
- No need to add or remove products manually

You can refer to [this module](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-dynamic-sale-category.html).